# Why isn't my solution to K&R exercise 2-3 working?

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve exercise 2-3 in the book *The C Programming Language*, but my solution isn't working and I can't find out what I did wrong. The exercise says to write a function that takes a string containing a hexadecimal number and returns that number as an `int`.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int htoi(char *s);

int main() {
    char s[5];
    scanf("%s", s);
    printf("%d", htoi(s));  
}

int htoi(char *s) {
    int length, num = 0, i;
    char c = 'A';
    for (length = 0; c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'; length++)
        c = toupper(s[length]);
    for (i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
        c = toupper(s[i]);
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            num += (c - '0') * pow(16, length - i);
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
            num += (c - 'A' + 10) * pow(16, length - i);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Please describe the problem. "It's not working" is not a problem description. What does your function do? (Not what it should do. What does it do?)

Comment: Using a debugger can help finding where the program behaves undesired so that you can check the logic is correct.

Comment: There's a function called `isxdigit()` you may use.. then instead of using `pow()`, you may multiply. *Hint:* 123 = (1*10 + 2)*10 + 3.

Comment: Note that code such as `c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'` implicitly relies on the ASCII character set.  Only the digit characters `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed by the C standard to be represented consecutively.

Comment: I'd start over.  `pow` is a bad choice for this purpose. A far better algorithm is to process characters in a loop with `val = (val << 4) + hexVal(ch)`, where `int val` is initially 0.  Find the `hexVal` of a character with `ch - '0'` for characters between 0 and 9.  For `'a'` through `'f'` use a `switch` statement with e.g. `case 'a': case 'A': return 10;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `pow(16, length - i)` to `pow(16, length - i - 2)`.

"Why 2?" you may ask.

Well, you need to learn how to debug programs. First of, your `length` does not seem to be properly calculated. Print that value and you'll see that it is actually one more than expected. Usually, C-programmers do not count the `'\0'` terminator when talking about the length of a string, and the standard function `strlen` does not either.

So you should remove 1 from length after it is calculated. And then it will make sense. For instance, 4=4*10⁰ and 40=4*10¹. The digit on position n should be raised to the power n-1. After that you use `pow(16, length - i - 1)`. Notice it's 1 instead of 2 when we have correct length.

**Other comments on your code**

Unless you have a specific reason to do so, I would not write a custom function to calculate the length. Instead, use `strlen` and check for correctness later. In this program it seems that you can assume that the string always will be correct. So I would have written it like this:

```
int htoi(char * s) {
    int length = strlen(s), num = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int factor = pow(16, length - i - 1), digit;
        int c = toupper(s[i]);
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            digit = c - '0';
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
            digit = c - 'A' + 10;
        num += digit * factor;
    }
    return num;
}
```

I also refactored it a little bit.

Comment: `NULL` is a pointer. `NUL` is a character. A string length, in C, never counts the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: @ManceRayder -- `NUL` exists in ASCII, EBCDIC, and some other character sets, but is never mentioned in the C Standard; there it is just called a null character, a null byte, or a null terminator.

Comment: @DavidBowling -- I'm not saying that C specifies or requires that. It's mentioned,  at §7.4, as an example of what a control character refers to.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- The buffer for input is too small and you do not pass its size to `scanf()`. If the user types more than 4 characters before the newline, you will have undefined behavior. It is much safer to use `fgets()` or at least specify the maximum number of characters to store with `scanf("%4s", s)`.
- You should test the return value of `scanf()` to prevent undefined behavior on invalid input, such as when redirecting from an empty file.
- The first loop in `htoi` attempts to count the number of characters that are digits or letters between `A` and `F`, but it incorrect as it includes the first mismatched character in the computed `length`. Furthermore is has undefined behavior on platforms where `char` is signed by default if the user typed exotic characters such as `é`.
- relying on floating point arithmetic for this calculation is both wasteful and potentially incorrect. There is a much simpler method whereby you multiply the current value of `num` by `16` and add the value of the current hexadecimal digit. In your approach the factor should be `pow(16, length - i -`);`if`length` had been computed correctly.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int htoi(const char *s);

int main() {
    char s[100];
    if (fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin))
        printf("%d\n", htoi(s));
    return 0;
}

int htoi(const char *s) {
    unsigned int num = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; isxdigit((unsigned char)s[i]); i++) {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            num = num * 16 + c - '0';
        else
            num = num * 16 + 10 + toupper(c) - 'A';
    }
    return num;
}
```